# c# .net api namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Hi all this question keeps ticking anytime I try a new project to test my skills as a beginner. I find that in most cases I have no clue what .NET namespaces I need to incorporate into my code and even if I find out (from here or youtube) I have to put the project on hold and go down ad exhausting rabbit hole before I resume. As a beginner can anyone advise me on what strategy you think will be appropriate to learn. I'm self-taught. Thanks

Comment: If you search the internet for "C# Something", you will likely find the documentation for the "Something" you are looking for, and that documentation likely will tell you what you are looking for.  LDAP was the most obscure thing I could think of when writing this comment (it's the "Lightweight Directory Access Protocol"), but "C# LDAP" pointed me to the `System.DirectoryService` namespace

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using an IDE like [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) or [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/). These IDEs help you to automatically select the appropriate .NET namespaces for the code you are writing, which will save you a lot of time as a beginner and as a professional.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give you the shortest easier answer I can with this to help you on your way.

You don't need to know what namespaces you're going to be using at the start of a project these are the kinds of things that show themselves over time.

For example you may decide that later on today you would like to get some elements out of a list where a certain condition needs to me met.

You may decide to do this inside of a loop or you could decide to use linq in which case you would need that to be imported.

The same goes for many other things such as collections, http, even something you have created yourself in the past.

So in short do not worry so much about the tools you will need as they will make themselves clear to you when the time comes.

Comment: Thanks, you've been helpful